# char** DllImport fails

Tags: c#, char, dllimport, pointer-to-pointer

I would like to DllImport the following function. Nevertheless, "ret" returns true, but my string array seems to be empty, so I think I may need some marshaling. Any tip is welcome! Thanks in advance :)

The C function:

```
bool getBootLog(char **a1);
```

The code below is for testing and does not work properly.

The DllImport:

```
[DllImport("ext.dll")]
public static extern bool getBootLog(string[] bootLog);
```

Current code:

```
        string[] bootLog = new string[1024 * 1024];
        bool ret = getBootLog(bootLog);

        foreach (string s in bootLog)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(s);
        }
```

2 more tries which do NOT work:

```
var ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr)));
try
{
    getBootLog(out ptr);
    var deref1 = (string)Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr);
    Debug.WriteLine(deref1);
}
finally
{
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
}

var ptr2 = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr)));
try
{
    getBootLog(out ptr2);
    var deref1 = (IntPtr)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr2, typeof(IntPtr));
    var deref2 = (string[])Marshal.PtrToStructure(deref1, typeof(string[]));
    Debug.WriteLine(deref2);
}
finally
{
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr2);
}
```

mohsen's idea:

```
[DllImport("Ext.dll")]
public static extern bool getBootLog(StringBuilder bootLog);

try
{
    int bufferSize = 50;
    StringBuilder bootLog = new StringBuilder(" ", bufferSize);
    Debug.WriteLine("Prepared bootLog...");
    getBootLog(bootLog);
    Debug.WriteLine("Bootlog length: " + bootLog.Length);
    string realString = bootLog.ToString();
    Debug.WriteLine("Bootlog: " + realString);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Xception: " + ex.ToString());
}
```

results in:

> Prepared bootLog... Bootlog length: 0 Bootlog:

Comment: Could you make the question a bit more specific?

Comment: The types string[] and char** are not the same. You'll need to call getBootLog passing a char**.

Comment: This function is very hard to call from a C program, it doesn't get better when you pinvoke.   The argument must be `out IntPtr`.  What's next is a blind guess but it has to start with Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi().  Pretty likely you'll have a memory leak.

Comment: @iwein: I need a working way in C# to call the C function. The way shown above only works partly.

Comment: @metaDom I was asking for you to edit the question to make that more clear…

Comment: more than likely use `ref IntPtr a1` as part of the signature on C# side, and use marshal allocation on the c# side, a buffer, which the onus is on OP to free the pointer to `IntPtr` allocated buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix up the declaration:

```
[DllImport("ext.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern bool getBootLog(ref IntPtr bootLogPtr);
```

The attempted lines in the edited version of the code looks to be incorrect.

```
var ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr)));
```

Really, the size of the buffer should be specified.

```
var ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(100); // Set it to 100 bytes, maximum!
```

Write the length in to the `ptr`, as its a C style null terminated string.

```
Marshal.WriteByte(ptr, 100, 0);
```

Then invoke the call which would be, top of my head:

```
IntPtr ptrBuf = ptr;
getBootLog(ref ptrBuf);
```

Copy the contents of the buffer by `ptrBuf` into string variable:

```
string sBootLog = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptrBuf);
```

Clean up the unmanaged memory contents:

```
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
```

Comment: I had the chance to influence the "log" and overwrite its content. I've set it to "XYZABC". If I print "string sBootLog" from your code, it contains "X". So it might be working, but not fully... Also a second test with "ABCXYZ" worked so far - printed "A".

Comment: ok, the problem was on my side. false interpretetion of the prototype: its not "bool getBootLog(char **a1)" but "int getBootLog(wchar_t **a1)". I'll post the fixed code once done...